# undefined reference to `__strtof128_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'

Tags: cross-platform, cross-compiling, glibc

I am trying to cross-compiling a packing to debian-8 (jessie), which comes with glibc-2.19. While cross-compiling the package it throwed the following error.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/opt/jessiesdk-cxx/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/ach/ros2/ros2_core/build/ament_index_cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_04f3a/fast"
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_04f3a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_04f3a.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ach/ros2/ros2_core/build/ament_index_cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_04f3a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++ --sysroot=/opt/jessiesdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_04f3a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/ach/ros2/ros2_core/build/ament_index_cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_04f3a
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_04f3a.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++ --sysroot=/opt/jessiesdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot       CMakeFiles/cmTC_04f3a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_04f3a 
    /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so: undefined reference to `__strtold_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so: undefined reference to `__strtof_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so: undefined reference to `__strtod_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /opt/jessiesdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so: undefined reference to `__strtof128_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_04f3a.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_04f3a' failed
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_04f3a] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ach/ros2/ros2_core/build/ament_index_cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_04f3a/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_04f3a/fast] Error 2


  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


---
Failed   <<< ament_index_cpp    [ Exited with code 1 ]
```

After a bit of googling i found [ABI Laboratory](https://abi-laboratory.pro/index.php?view=navigator&symbol=__strtof128_nan%40%40GLIBC_PRIVATE#result). Does this mean i require a glibc at least 2.26 in order to compile the package ?

Is there a way around this ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with the way the cross-compiler has been set up. 
It looks like your sysroot contains a copy of a newer `libm` along with the older `libc` for Debian jessie.

`__strtof128_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE` is an internal reference in the `libm` library of glibc, used to call into the `libc` library. These internal references only work properly if `libm` and `libc` were part of the same glibc build.

Comment: Thanks @Florian you are right. Not sure, why some of my libraries are pointing to my "/usr/local/..." after cross-compiling.